# How to access stringParam in groovy Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a job which takes stringParam and i am trying to access that stringParam from workflow, however i am getting No such property exception.

```
parameters {
        stringParam("COMMIT_SHA", "", "[Required] Short SHA of the commit used to build the image")
    }
 print "The commit sha val is: $env.COMMIT_SHA"
```

I have tried different options like ${params.COMMIT_SHA}, ${COMMIT_SHA}

Comment: You have a typo in your parameters directive: the function is `string`. The documentation should be helpful: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Modify your parameters block as follows

```
parameters { 
    string(name: 'COMMIT_SHA', defaultValue: '', description: '[Required] Short SHA of the commit used to build the image') 
}
```

You should then be able to reference it using `${params.COMMIT_SHA}` or `${COMMIT_SHA}` or `${env.COMMIT_SHA}`

Your syntax is for the Jobs DSL plugin but you stated you are using a pipeline.  If you are, in fact, using a Freestyle Job **to create other jobs** instead of a Pipeline please provide the entire script and I will update my answer.  However, your post appears to want to set the parameter for a pipeline ( not specify the metadata for the creation of a separate job via the Jobs DSL plugin )

The following Job DSL script, when executed, will create a Job called "example" with COMMIT_SHA as a parameter.  It won't be added as a parameter to the job that contains the Job DSL script

```
job('example') {
    parameters {
        stringParam('myParameterName', 'my default stringParam value', 'my description')
    }
}
```

> In other words, there is nothing to print in the job that contains the stringParam code because that code configures a different job to contain a string parameter, it doesn't add that parameter to the current job

Comment: Hi, I am kind of newbie to Devops, i am trying to checkout a particular commit from the master branch. I will update my question.

Comment: @prabhakarReddyG please do not do this.  Post a new question, send me the link, and delete this one.  I will answer it on the new post.  Editing to ask a new question is confusing to other users